# What does the name Daniel mean in Hebrew?

Tags: names, daniel-book-of, daniel-the-person

I know that the words are "Judge/judged" and Hashem's name.

However, which one of these is the meaning of the name:

1. HaShem is my judge
2. HaShem judged me

Comment: Is there any reason to think there is one objective answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root דן is to judge, with a trailing י it becomes דני, My Judge. ‎Therefore דניאל is The Lord is my Judge.

Comment: Wouldn't "my judge" be דייני?

Comment: If you want a literal translation as opposed to the intention, then you'll have to suffer a sentence form that is not comfortable in English. Expanding דניאל to דן אותי האל would be: "Judging me the Lord". However you see fit to form that into modern English is up to you, they're all valid so long as you retain 1) Present tense 2) The entity being judged is the literary "me", and 3) The entity doing the judging is the Lord.

Comment: How do you know the intention? Did דניאל's mom tell you? Were you at his brit milah?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3825225/jewish/Popular-Jewish-Hebrew-Boy-Names.htm#:%7E:text=Hebrew-,%22G%E2%80%91d%20is%20my%20Judge%22,-Dan%27l%2C%20Denel%2C%20Dan) list of names and the [Aish.com](https://www.aish.com/jl/l/b/48967016.html) list of names, it means "G‑d is my Judge."

(also, according to non-jewish sites, it means the present tense.)

Comment: Would it be more accurate to phrase it as "My judge is God", rather than "God is my judge"? It gives it a different emphasis in English at least.